# how do I install ack on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite, ack

i did this once before, but have since forgotten how. i seem to remember having the ack.pl file in an "opt" directory close to root level on my Mac. i also remember that i will need to update my path settings in my `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, etc. I hope someone can fill in the blanks with some detailed instructions on how to do this properly.

- please note that i would like to know how to do this WITHOUT using any 3rd-party software / package managers (Homebrew, MacPorts, etc.).

Comment: Did you do a CPAN install or the single-file version?

Comment: i did what i did before and went for the single file version like so - from this page - http://beyondgrep.com/install/ - i clicked the "single-file version of ack" link under "Install the ack executable" - then did "File" > "Save As..." and name it "ack.pl" (as i know it was named before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - found the answer myself. Here's how i did it on OS X 10.10 Yosemite (no "opt" directory, no messing w/ editing my $PATH in /.profile, etc.)...

1 - set permissions on the directory /usr/local/bin to have read/write access for everyone.

> (chmod 777 from Terminal - or - command + i from Finder, and set all to "Read & Write")

2 - then run the following command from the Terminal...

`curl http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.14-single-file > /usr/local/bin/ack && chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/ack`

> (obviously the path to the file on http://beyondgrep.com will change as they release newer versions, so update this adddress accordingly from information at - http://beyondgrep.com/install/

3 - change read/write permissions on /usr/local/bin back to 755
("Read & Write" by "system" only, group "wheel" and "everyone" set to "Read only")

and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options, but before those, you'll need to fire up Terminal.app (or iTerm.app if you use iTerm2) and `cd` to the directory you saved `ack.pl` (prbly `cd ~/Downloads`) and do:

```
$ chmod a+x ack.pl
```

so it's executable. You can test that with:

```
$ ./ack.pl --version
ack 2.14
Running under Perl 5.18.2 at /usr/bin/perl

Copyright 2005-2014 Andy Lester.

This program is free software.  You may modify or distribute it
under the terms of the Artistic License v2.0.
```

If you don't get something like that output something is wonky with your download.

To make it available as just `ack.pl` (you can also rename it to just `ack` btw), you can do:

```
$ sudo mv ack.pl /usr/bin
```

which will put it in a location already in your `PATH`.

If you have other non-Apple command-line software tools installed, then you may have a `/usr/local/bin` already setup. You can test that with:

```
$ ls -ald /usr/local/bin
drwxr-xr-x  861 bob  admin  29274 Dec  9 15:44 /usr/local/bin

$ echo $PATH | grep -c /usr/local/bin
1
```

If you don't get something similar to both results, then you don't have a `/usr/local/bin` readily accessible (so you can skip the following `mv`). If you *do* have something akin to both results, then you can just use that location by:

```
$ sudo mv ack.pl /usr/local/bin
```

(I'm only using `sudo` to avoid potential permissions issues, it may work fine w/o `sudo` for the `/usr/local/bin` move).

If neither of those are acceptable, then you can do:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin # it won't do anything bad if you already have one
$ mv ack.pl ~/bin
```

and then edit your `.profile` and add a line at the end with:

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Exit out of the terminal completely and go back in and you should be able to enter `ack.pl` at any shell prompt without prefix and it should run.